# how to show all custom options in right side in product view page with magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I added color,size and warranty in admin in custom options.I want to show these custom options in right column of product view page but it is not showing in right side.
can you please tell me how to show custom options in right side.

If anyone knows this,please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $_product->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $_product->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: no it is not working.can you please tell me the path where i have to use this code?

Answer (score 0):

Amit's code should work.   However, can you make sure that the attributes have Visible on Product View Page on Front-end set to yes.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is visible in product page but not coming in right column.I want to show custom options in right column though my product view page design is 2-columns right.